# Ansible & Vagrant: deploy in local and production with same playbook

Tags: vagrant, ansible

I've been working in a recipe for vagrant+virtualbox+ansible lately. I have some issues now I want to reuse the code of the recipe to be able to provision not just the local but the staging and production environment. My playbook is:

```
- hosts: all
  sudo: true
  pre_tasks:
  roles:
    - common
    - webserver
    - database
    - php
  post_tasks:
```

and my Vagrantfile

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/precise64"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.10.10.101"
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "nfs"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.gui = true
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "512"]
    vb.name = "testing"
  end

  config.vm.provision :ansible do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "playbook.yml"
    ansible.limit    = "local"
        ansible.inventory_path = "./inventory"
  end
end
```

So what happens? If I run

```
$ vagrant up
```

everything works fine but if I run

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventory playbook.yml --limit production
```

(where production is a group in inventory with a remote ip on ovh)

it fails because the playbook will need

```
user:root
```

parameter, but if I put this parameter on the playbook, then it fails when I run

```
$ vagrant provision
```

I know making some yml for local and remote will finish the issue, but I would prefer more elegant solution.

Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Didn't read all (will read it), but Vagrant normally are recommended for Dev environment.

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the ssh user per host in the inventory using group vars:

in group_vars/local:

```
ansible_ssh_user: vagrant
```

in group_vars/production:

```
ansible_ssh_user: root
```

Also consider using separate inventory files for vagrant and production. It doesn't allow you to run things on both envs at once, but that's hardly a common use case, and it's safer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on the [offical document: Using Vagrant and Ansible](http://docs.ansible.com/guide_vagrant.html)

try with `-u root`

```
$ ansible-playbook -i .vagrant/provisioners/ansible/inventory/vagrant_ansible_inventory --private-key=~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key -u vagrant playbook.yml
```